# How to make time delay repeat infinitely in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this code and it calls a function called tapped coin but I need this delay function to continue to repeat indefinitely so the user can simulate this automatic tap.

```
delay(1) {
    for i in 0...5 {
        print(i)
        self.tappedCoin()
    }
}
```

The delay function looks like this

```
func delay(delay: Double, closure: ()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        closure
    )
}
```

How can I get this to continue repeating every second without affecting anything else in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You can stop this loop by assigning `coinsEnabled = false`

```
var coinsEnabled = true
var counter = 0

func infiniteLoop() {
    print(counter)
    tappedCoin()
    delay(1) {
        [weak self] in
        if self?.coinsEnabled == true {
            self!.counter += 1
            self!.infiniteLoop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if let s = self where s.coinsEnabled {` would look a lot better and you wouldn't have to force-unwrap.

Answer (score -1):

What your code is doing is waiting for one second and then executing `self.tappedCoin()` five times immediately.

The best way to do this would be to use an `NSTimer` that repeats every second. Make sure you store it so you can stop it when it's appropriate.

*(I'm not going to go into detail with `NSTimer` because there are thousands of resources in SO an the web)*